# Building a POJO as a WAR using Maven

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, war

I have a java application (a standard POJO) that I have built and ran using Maven. Currently I'm using it as a Desktop application (JAR) but now I want to export the application as a WAR and run it on a tomcat server. How can I do this using Maven?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to do some changes to the application. In particular all the user interface code needs to be rewritten from what ever you use now to a web interface. Reconfiguring the build to create a war is likely the easier part. You can do this by using the war plugin.

Comment: Hi there, I have no UI for the app. Do you have any documentation you can give me on using the war plugin?

Comment: look here: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/